# XCopy is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to figure out why this code isn't working. I created something similar that works fine but this isn't working and not sure why. Does anyone know why?

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a-%%b-%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a-%%b)    
xcopy %ThisService_RootDirectory%"saves\*.*" %ThisService_RootDirectory%"backups\worlds\%mydate%_%mytime%" /E /I /Y
```

Comment: What about it "isn't working"?  What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I want it to copy the saves folder to the backups/wolds/%mydate%_%mytime% and include all the subfolders. It is not creating the folder %mydate%_%mytime% so I think something before is giving an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are off in the `XCopy` command to where they are in the middle of your path instead of at the start and end.

Update it to this:

```
REM Create the directory.
MKDIR "%ThisService_RootDirectory%backups\worlds\%mydate%_%mytime%"

REM Copy the files.
xcopy "%ThisService_RootDirectory%saves\*.*" "%ThisService_RootDirectory%backups\worlds\%mydate%_%mytime%" /E /I /Y
```

Your variable `%ThisService_RootDirectory%` should *not* be quoted in the respective `SET` statement since you are appending subdirectories to it.

For example:

```
REM Set this way [quotes around then entire declaration].
SET "ThisService_RootDirectory=C:\path\to\user\8\"

REM Do NOT set this way [quotes around just the path].
SET ThisService_RootDirectory="C:\path\to\user\8\"
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not copy the files over to the new directory. It did not create the new directory either.

Comment: @Ericode - What does your `SET ThisService_RootDirectory` line look like?

Comment: ThisService_rootDirectory looks like C:\path\to\user\8\

Comment: @Ericode - See the updated answer. I adjust the `SET` examples (to quote the _entire_ declaration) to prevent spaces on the end from messing it up. Additionally I adjusted the `MKDIR` and `Xcopy` commands to account for the trailing \ you are adding in your directory variable.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I think the issue is with the trailing "/".